# Renderizar tabelas em latex no rmarkdown

Tags: table, latex, r, markdown

Estou criando um arquivo html a partir de um arquivo em latex que já tenho. Para isso, gostaria de renderizar em html (usando o formato Rmd do Rstudio) a tabela complexa abaixo que usa `\usepackage{multirow}` no prêambulo do arquivo latex. Como fazer isso?

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Variáveis consideradas no estudo com suas respectivas categorias}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
Variáveis             & Categorias &  Descrição \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Y}    &  0&  Morte registrada como causas distintas de homicídio\\
                      &  1&  Morte registrada como homicídio\\
                                        \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{S}    &  1&  Masculino\\
                      &  2&  Feminino\\
                                            \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{R}    &  1&  Raça/Cor Branca\\
                      &  2&  Raça/Cor Negra\\
                      &  4&  Raça/Cor Parda\\
                      &  5&  Raça/Cor Indígena\\
                                            \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{ESC}  &  1&  Nenhum estudo\\
                      &  2&  1 a 3 anos de estudo\\
                      &  3&  4 a 7 anos de estudo\\
                      &  4&  8 a 11 anos de estudo\\
                      &  5&  12 ou mais anos de estudo\\
                                            \hline
          I           & Idade (Contínua) &15 a 17 anos \\
                    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Já procurei na internet mas não encontrei nada semelhante, pelo que entendi, tabelas do latex não são facilmente renderizadas em html e devo reconstruir toda a tabela em markdown. É isso mesmo, ou tenho alguma forma mais automatizada de fazer isso? Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar, não achei nada relacionado aos ambientes `tabular` e `table`, mas descobri que o markdown renderiza o ambiente `array`, ainda não descobri como adicionar os comandos `\multirow` e `\multicolumn`, vou deixar aqui o código que estou utilizando:

```
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\hline
\textrm{Variáveis}             &\textrm{ Categorias} &\textrm{  Descrição} \\
\hline
        \textrm{Y}&  0&  \textrm{Morte registrada como causas distintas de homicídio}\\
                  &  1&  \textrm{Morte registrada como homicídio}\\
                                        \hline
   \textrm{S}     &  1&  \textrm{Masculino}\\
                  &  2&  \textrm{Feminino}\\
                                        \hline
   \textrm{R}     &  1&  \textrm{Raça/Cor Branca}\\
                  &  2&  \textrm{Raça/Cor Negra}\\
                  &  4&  \textrm{Raça/Cor Parda}\\
                  &  5&  \textrm{Raça/Cor Indígena}\\
                                        \hline
    \textrm{ESC}  &  1&  \textrm{Nenhum estudo}\\
                  &  2&  \textrm{1 a 3 anos de estudo}\\
                  &  3&  \textrm{4 a 7 anos de estudo}\\
                  &  4&  \textrm{8 a 11 anos de estudo}\\
                  &  5&  \textrm{12 ou mais anos de estudo}\\
                                        \hline
      \textrm{I}  & \textrm{Idade (Contínua)} &\textrm{15 a 17 anos} \\
                \hline
\end{array}
```